# Heroku - How can I undo a push on heroku?

Tags: heroku

After pushing my app on heroku, my app crashes.
I don't want to make a git rebase before getting heroku last version (if I do so, I'll get fast-forward errors...)

I would be pleased to know if there is a command to do it (I don't find it on the heroku doc)

Thank you!

Comment: heroku rollback --app "your-app-name"

Comment: @Devi your command works, tks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `git push heroku --force` to push your local `HEAD`.

Answer (score 84):

actually now heroku has a rollback!

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/11/17/releases/

```
heroku rollback
```

Comment: This doesn't get rid of higher versions on the Heroku remote, though.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what @GrantBirchmeier said, rolling back on Heroku will only 'reactivate' a previous commit, it won't actually change the repository on Heroku. So if you were to then pull and push your Heroku remote (which should usually do nothing), you'll actually redeploy the commit that you rolled back. I just got stung by this this week. Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Comment: In cases where a new push causes crashes, rollback seems superior. It's faster, an almost immediate way to stop the crashing by reverting to a prior release. And when you push the next commit that fixes the problem, that intermediate bad commit is irrelevant.